# sending mails using sendgrid from azure app-service webjob

Tags: azure, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have developed a C# console application sending emails to our customers when certain conditions occur. Mails are not sent when application is deployed as azure webjob.

When testing from visual studio in my development environment Mails are sent without any problems as intended, but when the application is deployed and run as an azure app-service webjob no mails are sent. The application is otherwise working as intended also when deployed as azure webjob.

```
public enum MailType : short { Plain, Html }

private static string MimeType(MailType type) 
{ return (type == MailType.Html) ? "text/html" : "text/plain";  }

private static async Task sendMail(string to, string name, string subject, MailType mailType, string content)
{
    SendGridMessage msg = new SendGridMessage();
    msg.From = new EmailAddress("noreply@foo.org", "Foo Ltd.");
    msg.AddTo(to, name);
    msg.Subject = subject;
    msg.AddContent(MimeType(mailType), content);
    SendGridClient client = new SendGridClient(SendGridAPIKey);
    await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
}

public static void SendMail(string to, string name, string subject, MailType mailType, string content)
{
    sendMail(to, name, subject, mailType, content).Wait();
}
```

Answers to all other questions regarding this issue (a lot of developers have met this problem) focus on the code; especially the async implementation, but it seems this is not the issue. Does azure have some restrictions to the communication between the application deployed as webjob and the sendgrid server? (I am using the sendgrid and sendgrid.helpers.mail)

Comment: When you publish the webjob to azure,  have you set `SendGridAPIKey` in `Configuration` in azure webapp?

Comment: Checking the SendGridAPIKey revealed a bug, but fixing it did not solve the problem. Requests from the application when deployed as azure webjob are not logged in the SendGrid activity list (but request from my dev. environment are)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this and if yes, what was the solution?

Comment: I didn't resolve the SendGrid problem and use MailJet instead

Answer (score 0):

I test with you code and it work well both on local and on Azure. I invoke the `SendMail` method in a queueTrigger.

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue1")] string message, TextWriter log)
{
    log.WriteLine(message);
    SendMail("xxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxx", "hello world", MailType.Plain, "have a good day.");
}
```

So you could refer to the following ways to troubleshoot it.

1.Check your `SendGridAPIKey`. If you stored `SendGridAPIKey` as an environment variable in the project, you need to go to `Configuration`>`Application Settings` and add the key in it.

2.Check your SendGrid Activity.The problem could be getting your request to SendGrid, or it could be that SendGrid is getting your request but isn't fulfilling it. Check the Activity Feed and search for the particular email you are expecting

Comment: Checking the SendGridAPIKey revealed a bug, but fixing it did not solve the problem. Requests from application as azure webjob are not logged in the SendGrid activity list.

Comment: Do you mind republish a webjob? I test in my site and it all work fine.

Comment: Any update now? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)

Comment: Hi Joey I cannot see what change you suggest. The problem is not yet solved.